# what's difference between tokenizer.encode and tokenizer.encode_plus in Hugging Face

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Here is an example of doing sequence classification using a model to determine if two sequences are paraphrases of each other. The two examples give two different results. Can you help me explain why `tokenizer.encode` and `tokenizer.encode_plus` give different results?

Example 1 (with `.encode_plus()`):

```py
paraphrase = tokenizer.encode_plus(sequence_0, sequence_2, return_tensors="pt")
not_paraphrase = tokenizer.encode_plus(sequence_0, sequence_1, return_tensors="pt")

paraphrase_classification_logits = model(**paraphrase)[0]
not_paraphrase_classification_logits = model(**not_paraphrase)[0]
```

Example 2 (with `.encode()`):

```py
paraphrase = tokenizer.encode(sequence_0, sequence_2, return_tensors="pt")
not_paraphrase = tokenizer.encode(sequence_0, sequence_1, return_tensors="pt")

paraphrase_classification_logits = model(paraphrase)[0]
not_paraphrase_classification_logits = model(not_paraphrase)[0]
```

Comment: Can you please specify your version of `transformers`, give at least the sample sentences you tested with, and the model version you are using (BERT, RoBERTa, etc.). See [mcve] for an explanation of what  an ideal sample should look like.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The main difference is stemming from the additional information that `encode_plus` is providing. If you read the documentation on the respective functions, then there is a slight difference for[`encode()`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode):

> Converts a string in a sequence of ids (integer), using the tokenizer and vocabulary.
>   Same as doing `self.convert_tokens_to_ids(self.tokenize(text))`.

and the description of [`encode_plus()`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode_plus):

> Returns a dictionary containing the encoded sequence or sequence pair
>   **and additional information**: the mask for sequence classification and
>   the overflowing elements if a `max_length` is specified.

Depending on your specified model and input sentence, the difference lies in the additionally encoded information, specifically the input mask. Since you are feeding in two sentences at a time, BERT (and likely other model variants), expect some form of masking, which allows the model to discern between the two sequences, see [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#transformers.BertTokenizer.create_token_type_ids_from_sequences). Since `encode_plus` **is** providing this information, but `encode` **isn't**, you get different output results.

Answer (score 9):

The tokenizer.encode_plus function combines multiple steps for us:

1.- Split the sentence into tokens.
2.- Add the special [CLS] and [SEP] tokens.
3.- Map the tokens to their IDs.
4.- Pad or truncate all sentences to the same length.
5.- Create the attention masks which explicitly differentiate real tokens from [PAD] tokens.

Documentation is [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer?highlight=encode_plus#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizer.encode_plus)

```
# Tokenize all of the sentences and map the tokens to thier word IDs.
input_ids = []
attention_masks = []

# For every sentence...
for sent in sentences:
    # `encode_plus` will:
    #   (1) Tokenize the sentence.
    #   (2) Prepend the `[CLS]` token to the start.
    #   (3) Append the `[SEP]` token to the end.
    #   (4) Map tokens to their IDs.
    #   (5) Pad or truncate the sentence to `max_length`
    #   (6) Create attention masks for [PAD] tokens.
    encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                        sent,                      # Sentence to encode.
                        add_special_tokens = True, # Add '[CLS]' and '[SEP]'
                        max_length = 64,           # Pad & truncate all sentences.
                        pad_to_max_length = True,
                        return_attention_mask = True,   # Construct attn. masks.
                        return_tensors = 'pt',     # Return pytorch tensors.
                   )
```